# Run jekyll automatically on system startup or when I login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jekyll

I want to run jekyll in --detached mode when I login to my Ubuntu system.

Currently I am running manually with the following command.

```sh
cd ~/Blog/ && bundle exec jekyll serve -B
```

Is there any way this could be (re)started automatically during system start up or after I login to my Ubuntu system?

Jekyll, bundle, ruby and gem are installed only for current user.

Other useful info to answer this question -

```sh
$ which jekyll
/home/nayab/gems/bin/jekyll
$ which gem
/home/nayab/.rbenv/shims/gem
$ which bundle
/home/nayab/gems/bin/bundle
$ which ruby
/home/nayab/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

Comment: did you try writing a cronjob triggered at system startup? or do you need help with the same ?

Comment: Jekyll is installed for specific user. How do you run the program with user environment?

Comment: try adding a cronjob while logged into the user environment, as for as i know crontab entries are privilege separated for users and root. So it must hold good as long as the user has permissions to run jekyll